# how to remove the html tag in iphone while parsing?

Tags: iphone, html, xml-parsing

hai guys while parsing some of the html tags are add in the array i need to remove that tag

example

```
<img src=http://www.browndailyherald.com/polopoly_fs/1.2421290!image/4027750474.jpg_gen/thumbnails/100x100/4027750474.jpg><br /><br><p>
Andrew Furnas '11 has been named a recipient of the Marshall Scholarship, a nationally competitive fellowship which sponsors two years of graduate study in the United Kingdom....</p>
```

i need to remove that `<img>` tag and display only the content

please help me

Comment: I think its something to do with CDATA - google it

Comment: @benhowdle89- hai i not aware about CDATA.... i'm not using that too

Answer (score 0):

Store it in an **NSSMutableString** , then use the function **deleteCharactersInRange** to remove what you don't want.

You will need to decide what the range is by searching the **NSMutableString**.

All the solutions can be found easily on google.

Comment: hai it works thanks but i need to do this for different type of xmlparsing with same class. each parsing is differ from other so its works only for the particular parsing

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Three20Core](http://three20.info/) to remove HTML tags.

```
 [yourString stringByRemovingHTMLTags];
```

Comment: hai i'm not using Facebook in my app please give me the simple solution

Comment: You don't need to use facebook. It does not get any simpler than this. You just need to install three20core (there is a python script to help you with that), and then add NSStringAdditions.